# multidimensional array for a discussion board

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array of a discussion.

I'm using a recursive function (see below) to echo the values (comments) of this array. But with my function only the first child comment (per array level) appears.

How can I adapt this function, so that I can echo all child comments per array level, like in a normal discussion board?

In this example array the comment_id "4" and the comment_id "7" are on the same level, but with my current function only comment_id "4" comments is viewed.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 1
            [comment_content] => This is a comment...
            [child] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [comment_id] => 3
                            [comment_content] => This is a reply to the comment...
                            [child] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [comment_id] => 4
                                            [comment_content] => This is a reply to the reply...
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [comment_id] => 7
                                            [comment_content] => This is a another reply to the reply...
                                            [child] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 2
            [comment_content] => This is another comment...
            [child] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [comment_id] => 6
            [comment_content] => This is another comment...
            [child] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

My current function looks like this:

```
function RecursiveWrite($array) {
    foreach ($array as $vals) {
        echo $vals['comment_content'] . "\n";
        RecursiveWrite($vals['child']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of an array you are using?

Comment: Hey Jennifer, the code you posted here is fine. You'll have to post some more code for us to help you find the bug. If comment 7 isn't printed at all, then perhaps (a) your loop has a "break" or "return" statement in it, or (b) there's an error that ends the whole script. Or if the code is fairly complex, it could be anything, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe i don't understand you question, but function seems fine.

I've just added spacer and comment_id into your function

```
function RecursiveWrite($array, $spacer='') {
    foreach ($array as $vals) {
        echo $spacer . $vals['comment_id'] . ' - ' . $vals['comment_content'] . "\n";
        RecursiveWrite($vals['child'], $spacer . '  ');
    }
}
```

And it outputs

```
1 - This is a comment...
  3 - This is a reply to the comment...
    4 - This is a reply to the reply...
    7 - This is a another reply to the reply...
2 - This is another comment...
6 - This is another comment...
```

Comment: You were absolutely right...the function was ok... I was doing some other thing wrong. Thanks a lot.